# How to check the checkbox by default?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to check the checkbox based on the DB data.

I have something like

```
<div ng-controller="test">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="check(item)" ng-      
        checked="checkAll"/> {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
app.controller("test", function($scope)
{
  //getting items data....
  //codes...

  //set item 0 to be selected
  $scope.items[0].isSelected = true;
}
```

However, I can't seem to make the `item[0]` selected by default. How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in the code that you posted - but otherwise, it should work.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("test", function($scope)
{
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.items.push({isSelected:true, name:'test'});
  $scope.items[0].isSelected = true;
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" /> {{item.name}}
    </div>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set ng-init (without the controller setting):

```
<div ng-controller="test">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-init="item.isSelected=true" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="check(item)" ng-      
        checked="checkAll"/> {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```